# How to input filePath on FileReader

Tags: java

I have this code that Reads a file from the file path given. 
I have hardcoded F://dom.txt. I need the user to input that filepath instead.
How should i do it? Thanks

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class BuffReader extends Converter {

private static BufferedReader br() throws FileNotFoundException{
    return new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F://dom.txt")); //<--filepath
}


static String strTem;

public static String readData(String Message){
    try{
        System.out.print(Message);
        strTem = br().readLine();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Muling tingan ang iyong numerong ibinigay");
    }
    return strTem;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to give the filename to the oddly-named `br()` method. For example:

```
private static BufferedReader br(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
}

public static String readData(String message){
    try{
        System.out.print(message);
        strTem = br(message).readLine();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Muling tingan ang iyong numerong ibinigay");
    }
    return strTem;
}
```

That's assuming the parameter to `readData` is actually the file you want to read from... otherwise, you'll need to work out where you *are* going to get the file name from.

(It would be a good idea to work on exception handling and naming, by the way.)

Comment: I may be misunderstanding him, but I think he's asking how to get the value from the user in the first place, not that he's got it in his message variable.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond. What i need is to have the filepath given by the user. W/ my code, it is hardcoded to "F://dom.txt" only. The user should Type the path desired to the command prompt. thanksss :)

Comment: @domdeleon: So which part are you finding difficult? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: regarding your answer. you've added "path" inside the filereader. That is what i want to do. But how should i make the path accept the value inputted by  the user? :)

Comment: @domdeleon: So is your question *really* "How do I get a value from the user?" If so, that has *nothing* to do with `FileReader`. This is why it's important to be clear in your question.

Comment: I am sorry. > How do i get value from the user that the FileReader will read. Whereas the value will be the link of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the input should come from the console (it could also be command line parameter or a gui or whatever you like really) then you should be able to use `System.console().readLine("prompt for input")`

Answer (score 0):

(assuming it is a standalone) Change your main method to read the variable args[0].

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    readData(Message, args[0]);
}
```

Then change the method signatures for `readData()` and so on. Basically the above code tells you how to read a string from command line.

If you are asking in the middle of the program:

You can use

```
System.console().readLine("Enter file name: )
```

to get the user input.

Also i would suggest to keep this file in a config file and read it from the file in order for the program to be flexible.

Comment: this is a class extended by other class. I just need to make the filepath i have hardcoded F://dom.txt" as dynamic. Meaning inputted by the user. :) thanks